# how to pass 2D arrays through a function without using pointers in C

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers, 2d

In my program I want to pass a pre initialized 2D array through a function. I am getting the 1st element correctly but rest of them are initialized to 0 while passing. I am not getting why this problem is arising. I don't want to use pointers to pass array. Please tell if I can pass my 2D array without using pointers .
Here is the code -

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define MAX(a,b) (a>b)?a:b

int kat(int S,int A[][S])
{
  int i,j,r[S];
  r[0] = A[0][0];
  j = 0;
  for(i=1;i<S;i++)
  {
     r[i] = MAX(r[i-1] + A[i][j],r[i-1] + A[i][j+1]);
     if (r[i-1] + A[i][j] < r[i-1] + A[i][j+1])
     j = j+1;
  }
  return r[S-1];
}

int main()
{
  int A[100][100],T,S,i,j,k,ans;
  scanf("%d",&T);
  while(T--)
  {
     i=0;
     scanf("%d",&S);
     for(k=1;k<=S;k++)
     {
       for(i;i<k;i++)
       {
         for(j=0;j<=i;j++)
         {
           scanf("%d",&A[i][j]);
         }
       }
     }
     ans = kat(S,A);
     printf("%d\n",ans);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are lying to the compiler: you tell it that the array that you are going to pass to `kat` is `int[][S]`, where `S` is a variable, but in realty you are passing it an array `int[][100]`, where `100` is a constant.

You can fix this by declaring the array *after* reading `S` in the `main`, like this:

```
scanf("%d",&S);
int A[S][S];
```